# replace Windows8 on Lenovo Ideapad with Ubuntu 12.04 server

Tags: lenovo

I'm trying to replace Win8 with Ubuntu server 12.04 on a new Lenovo S210 laptop 
(4GB mem, 500GB h/d).

I downloaded the iso to a USB stick, disabled UEFI, then tried to reboot but 
all I see is the date/time screen. The USB stick light has been pulsing on/off 
for about 30 min. Who/what are the usual suspects...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are running into issues because the usb stick does have the .iso but is not bootable. Check out http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/ This utility will help you make a bootable usb stick so you can install linux from it.

Good luck.

Comment: worked - now that helped to expose a subsequent error related to UEFI boot priority order. Menu only shows "Windows Boot Manager